# How can one create various arrangements of two or more types of atoms (like O, N etc.) with distinct coverages on a metal surface?

Tags: vasp, molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, python, atomic-simulation-environment

How can I modify the procedure described in this [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10875/1554) to achieve adsorption of two or more types of atoms on a surface, each with distinct coverages?

Is there an extension to the described method for generating random positions to accommodate the adsorption of multiple atom types with varying coverages?

Comment: please refer to this answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10875/1554

Comment: Thank you so much @Jaafar Mehrez i have very small query, if I wish to adsorb two types of atoms, like CO and O with different coverage. can you suggest that tag for modify this code?

Comment: Agrawi, I suggest you to ask new questions seperately or modify your question to incldue the the details you are asking for. I am not the author of the tool and I didn't use it. Hopefully Shaun Han (the author) will see the question and answer you.

Comment: Okey !! @Jaafar Mehrez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACAT dev here. Yes you can add different adsorbates, each with distinct coverage. However, you will need to use a more general [`acat.build.adlayer.RandomPatternGenerator`](https://asm-dtu.gitlab.io/acat/build.html#acat.build.adlayer.RandomPatternGenerator) class. Below is an example which you generate 10 random adlayer patterns on a Ni(211) surface with 2/18 ML C*, 3/18 ML N* and 4/18 ML O*:

```
from acat.build.adlayer import RandomPatternGenerator as RPG
from acat.adsorption_sites import SlabAdsorptionSites
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.build import fcc211

slab_211 = fcc211('Ni', (6,3,4), vacuum=5.)
sas_211 = SlabAdsorptionSites(slab_211, surface='fcc211')

rpg = RPG(slab_211, adsorbate_species='C', # add 2/18 ML C*
          min_adsorbate_distance=1.5,
          adsorption_sites=sas_211,
          trajectory='test1.traj')
rpg.run(num_gen=10, action='add', num_act=2)
images = read('test1.traj', index=':')
rpg = RPG(images, adsorbate_species='N', # add 3/18 ML N*
          min_adsorbate_distance=1.5,
          adsorption_sites=sas_211,
          trajectory='test1.traj',
          )
rpg.run(num_gen=10, action='add', num_act=3)
images = read('test1.traj', index=':')
rpg = RPG(images, adsorbate_species='O', # add 4/18 ML O*
          min_adsorbate_distance=1.5,
          adsorption_sites=sas_211,
          trajectory='test1.traj',
          )
rpg.run(num_gen=10, action='add', num_act=4)
images = read('test1.traj', index=':')
view(images[0])
```

[image]